# Is it compulsory to override equals() and hashCode() methods for final classes

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

Is it compulsory to override the methods `equals()` and `hashCode()` for final classes?

**Note :** as all Wrapper classes are final and immutable and overrides the equals and hashCode methods.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What info makes you think that since a class is final it shouldn't override equals/hashcode?

Comment: thanks @Takendarkk, I mentioned the info in the Note why i got this tinking. i wanted to know in which circumstances we need to override

Comment: Actually your note would suggest that you should believe the complete opposite of what your question title is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is it compulsary to override equals and hashCode methods for classes
>   which are defined as final?

Define a class as `final` and overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` are two different things.

Final is there to restrict a class not to be sub classed. And, `equals()` is there to check the equality of the instances of a class.